# Default Docker private registry installation Ubuntu

Tags: docker-registry

I installed docker registry 2.0 in a Ubuntu 14.04, following the official site: https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/

It will be used for testing so the development so I don't think we need a production instance:

- All clients will be 1.6 so just registry 2.0 required
- We don't need any kind of authentication

I install it:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 registry:2.0
```

Then I prepare a new image for docker:

```
docker tag ubuntu:14.04 juandapc:5000/ubuntu:14.04
docker tag ubuntu:14.04 juandapc:5000/ubuntu:14.04
```

I've replace localhost as in docs for juandapc, the machine hostname.

Howerver when I try to access the repository from another machine (telnet juandapc 5000) I get this error:

```
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://juandapc:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp 192.168.1.50:5000: connection refused. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry juandapc:5000` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/juandapc:5000/ca.crt
```

If I pull, same error:

```
# docker pull juandapc:5000/ubuntu
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://juandapc:5000/v1/_ping: tls: oversized record received with length 20527. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry juandapc:5000` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/juandapc:5000/ca.crt
```

Do I need to configure nginx? Documentation install nginx for production mode with registry 1.6 and 2.0 but it's not my case...

The firewall in the host (juandapc):

```
# iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere            
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.5           172.17.0.5           tcp dpt:5000

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5000 to:172.17.0.5:5000
```

Ports from the host juandapc (ESCUCHAR is LISTEN):

```
# netstat -natp
Conexiones activas de Internet (servidores y establecidos)
Proto  Recib Enviad Dirección local         Dirección remota       Estado       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               ESCUCHAR    919/sshd        
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.50:22        172.30.164.14:38412     ESTABLECIDO 3924/sshd: administ
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    ESCUCHAR    919/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    ESCUCHAR    3651/docker-proxy
```

5000 is there, but no ipv4????

The registry in the container:

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
1978cdff5e8c        registry:2.0        "registry cmd/regist   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   mad_shockley 

# docker exec mad_shockley ps -ax
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ssl    0:00 registry cmd/registry/config.yml
   14 ?        Rs     0:00 ps -ax
```

From juandpc I can get into the container:

```
# docker exec -t -i mad_shockley /bin/bash
root@1978cdff5e8c:/go/src/github.com/docker/distribution# hostname
1978cdff5e8c
```

Comment: Have you made sure your iptables on juandapc is letting tcp 5000 through INPUT?  Also please 1) exec a shell in the running registry container and make sure registry is running (ps -ax) 2) make sure it is listening on local 5000 (netstat -nap | grep 5000 | grep LISTEN) from the host)

Comment: You don't *need* nginx but as of right now it's probably a good idea...

Comment: I completed my question. I think iptables is right, and also the container. Anything else? nginx good idea in my case? why?

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on now.  Missed it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message was the key:

```
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://juandapc:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp 192.168.1.50:5000: connection refused. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry juandapc:5000` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/juandapc:5000/ca.crt
```

Added this line: /etc/default/docker:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry juandapc:5000"
```

Restarted docker and perfect!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I've always the same issue. Any kind of idea?
I've already restarted docker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

The remote host part of your tag must contain the name of the remote registry, not the name of the local (pushing/publishing) client.

So, in this case:

```
 juandapc:5000/ubuntu:14.04
```

should be

```
 <registry-server>:5000/ubuntu:14.04
```

where you replace <registry-server> with whatever machine you set up the registry on.   As it is, you're trying to push from juandapc to a remote repository on juandapc, and since that doesn't exist, connection refused...

If juandapc is actually where you installed the service, on the other hand - you have DNS / name resolution problems.  (Did you add an /etc/hosts entry for juandapc?  Why does it resolve to 192.168.1.50, instead of the actual address of the interface that netstat shows?)

Comment: I've tried with two machines and I've mixed code. Now it's ok. juandapc is 192.168.1.50 and is the machine where I've executed docker run -d -p 5000:5000 registry:2.0. In the other machine I have an entry in /etc/hosts with: 192.168.1.50    juandapc.

Comment: Should I use as registry-server 1978cdff5e8c? See my question edited once more